# Send data from rsyslog to a application/script

Tags: ubuntu, rsyslog

So I currently have a rsyslog server running on ubuntu that is inserting into a db , this is all fine but I want to do some processing before the insert , I have a script that can do the formatting me but im not sure how to i direct rsyslog to send it to the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can have rsyslog send it to an executable by using a shell execute "^" action. However, at that point the script must insert it into the DB as rsyslog does no more processing. Otherwise, you could attempt to use rsyslog's limited "property replacer" language to define a template to do whatever formatting you want.

Comment: I have already tried that , specifically I am calling a python script and it does not seem to be calling the script

Comment: Post a simple test rsyslog.conf and Python script, so we can help you figure out the problem.  rsyslog *can* do this.