# Alternative Logging applications for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nosql

I am trying to find another logging application that will allow me to log to CouchDb.

I am currently using rsyslog which is fine for logging to a mysql but doesnt seem to want to allow me to log couchdb or [even let me make calls to a external script](https://serverfault.com/questions/165371/send-data-from-rsyslog-to-a-application-script) that does the calls.

Comment: embobo was correct.  You can log to an external program with rsyslog.  I think you dropped that attempt too soon.  You should add more info to that question.

Comment: I tried to wits end to get that working , no matter how much i tried i couldn't get it to work (i.e. to call a external app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[syslog-ng](http://www.balabit.com/network-security/syslog-ng/) might fulfill the job, it's very configurable and with a bit of imagination can usually be tuned to do anything. It's also available in Ubuntu's package repository so it is simple to install.